# Regular curve differentiation

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, arc-length

[On page 6](http://people.math.gatech.edu/~ghomi/LectureNotes/LectureNotes1U.pdf) is this exercise:

" $s(t) = \int^t_a||\alpha'(u)||du$

Show that if $\alpha$ is a regular curve, i.e., $||\alpha'|| \neq$ 0
for all $t ∈ I$, then $s(t)$ is an invertible function, i.e., it is one-to-one (Hint: compute $s'(t)$)."

I am at a loss at how to differentiate s(t). How is it performed?

Comment: First fundamental theorem of calculus

Comment: By the fundamental theorem of calculus $s'(t) = ||\alpha'(t)||>0$ for all $t$

Comment: @Mixel Fundamental Theorem of Calculus

Comment: Fundamental theorem of calculus + regular curve + inverse function theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if $x<y$ then $s(y)-s(x) = \int_x^y \|\alpha'(t)\| dt > 0$, hence
$s$ is a strictly increasing continuous function, hence invertible on its range.